# WPF - Selector - Custom Control - SelectionChanged Event Not Firing

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, selector, itemtemplate, selectionchanged

I am new to custom control creation.  I have laid some groundwork for a new custom control based on the Selector class.  My understanding was that I should use this class since I needed the control to have an Items collection and the ability to handle selections.  I believe that changing the ItemTemplate may have overriden some of this ability because I do not receive the SelectionChanged event at the control level or application level.  I would think if I'm right that there is some sort of SelectionRegion XAML tag that I can put the DataTemplate innards into.  I have not had luck in finding anything like this.  After looking through Google for a while, I am ready to just ask.  What am I missing?  Below is the ItemTemplate markup.  Thanks for any help.  Thanks even more if you can tell me why the Text in TextBlock is enclosed in parentheses even though the data isn't.

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" Background="White" MinHeight="12" MinWidth="50"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

At the request of a commenter, here is the complete XAML for the control so far:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SourceMedicalWPFCustomControlLibrary">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MultiStateSelectionGrid}">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" Foreground="Black" Background="White" MinHeight="12" MinWidth="50" Padding="2" ToolTip="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MultiStateSelectionGrid}">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the anemic code-behind as well:

```
namespace SourceMedicalWPFCustomControlLibrary
{
    public class MultiStateSelectionGridState
    {
        public Brush Background { get; set; }
        public Brush Foreground { get; set; }
        public Brush Border { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public MultiStateSelectionGridState()
        {
            Background = Brushes.White;
            Foreground = Brushes.Black;
            Border = Brushes.Black;
            Text = String.Empty;
        }
    };

    public class MultiStateSelectionGrid : Selector
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object), typeof(MultiStateSelectionGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |
                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentMeasure));

        public object Content
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StatesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("States", typeof(List<MultiStateSelectionGridState>), typeof(MultiStateSelectionGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<MultiStateSelectionGridState>(),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public List<MultiStateSelectionGridState> States
        {
            get { return (List<MultiStateSelectionGridState>)GetValue(StatesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StatesProperty, value); }
        }

        static MultiStateSelectionGrid()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MultiStateSelectionGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MultiStateSelectionGrid)));
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            this.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(MultiStateSelectionGrid_SelectionChanged);
        }

        void MultiStateSelectionGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We need more detail, what is the full xaml of your control and the code behind, or view model if using mvvm?

Comment: from my understanding of a selector class, if you derive from it then the selection event need to be handled by yourself, whether it's via mouse click, touch, or keyboard. if you want to have an already implemented selection event, use listview or listbox instead. CMIIW.

Comment: @dnr3 So, the point of using the Selector class is just that it has all the member variables to support selection?  That seems a little useless.

Comment: @JKing So little is done at this point that I see no harm in that.  I will add an edit.

Comment: @BillyD sorry for the late reply but yeah that's what I understand from a selector class, I've tried to create one too derived from it but since I have to control when the selection change event fire (by clicking of mouse, or mouseleftbuttondown and so on) and got tired of it I decided to use listview as the base control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading some full code examples of different controls, I believe my answer is that I am doing this all wrong.  Instead, I need to have control that has a Selector like a ListBox in the ControlTemplate.  THEN, @JKing 's advice would help me get to where I need to be.  The answer to the actual question asked though is the aforementioned change from using Selector as a base class to having a selector in the template for the control.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Makes sense, I was having trouble trying to figure out what you were trying to accomplish, good luck.  I recommend staring with a visual studio template for custom controls and then researching some of the autocomplete text box examples in google, they have examples on textbox that filters listbox results.

Answer (score 1):

here is what I do.  I use the apply template function of the custom control and add a handlerto the selection chnaged event of the control I want.

simple sample here:

```
public event EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> YourControlSelectionChanged;

private void Selector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListSelectionChanged != null) {
        ListSelectionChanged(sender, e);
    }
}

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    //find or declare your control here, the x:name in xaml should be YourControl
    YourControl== this.Template.FindName("YourControl", this) as YourControlType
    YourControl.SelectionChanged += ResultListBox_SelectionChanged;
}
```

you can then bind to the name of the public event (YourControlSelectionChanged) you declared in your custom control class in xaml.

hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like you are thinking of this as a user control.  I may be wrong.  In your example, the class in which OnApplyTemplate resides is a Selector. What I am looking for is a way to catch the RoutedEvent from either the TextBlock or Border in the ItemTemplate and feed it into the Selector base class so that it works its magic in telling me which Item was selected at the new custom control class level.  Then, I can do whatever processing I need to before sending out an event to the window level that a selection changed has occurred.

Comment: By the way, I did try using a variation of your logic to name the Border in the ItemTemplate and add a delegate there.  It can't find the name though.  I figure this is because the this.Template may not include the Resources or it may be missing due to the fact that no data exists (no items were necessary to render yet).

Comment: This is defninitly from a custom control.  Your custom control derives from the base Selector which has a selectionchnaged event.  I don't see why this event won't give you want you want.  As i see it you are just looking to be notified of the change of selection/object in your code behind.  If you don't want to expose this event of your custom control you can still use it in your custom control "code behind" to handle your control logic.  Why do you need the textblock or border to generate this event?

Comment: when you create a custom control there is usually a file called Generic.xaml in a Themes folder in your project.  That is where you define your custom control "Parts" and that is where the template.find("name") looks for the control

Comment: did you start with the visual studio built in template for custom controls?

Comment: I need TextBlock or Border or some UIElement of an item to tell the Selector class that a selection has been made.  At first I just defined what the control would look like and tried added a SelectionChanged="myEventHandler" attribute to the custom control in a test application.  As I clicked, no selection change event was being fired from the applications viewpoint.  That's why I have gone down this rabbit hole of trying to figure out why the UI elements aren't notifying the Selector class that the click happened which is how the Selector knows to change the Selection.